# Local Variables offset from stack base pointer

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to learn more about the stack and base pointer. The following sample assembly code is from an objdump of a binary compiled by gcc on an IA32.

```
08048e0b <func_3>:
8048e0b:    55                      push   %ebp
8048e0c:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048e0e:    83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
8048e11:    8d 45 f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
8048e14:    89 44 24 0c             mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
8048e18:    8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
8048e1b:    89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
8048e1f:    c7 44 24 04 65 9b 04    movl   $0x8049b65,0x4(%esp)
```

I know that the base pointer `%ebp` is used to reference the function parameters and local variables. Normally the positive offsets are parameters passed to the function and the negative offsets are local variables?

On the line `8048e18:  8d 45 f4  lea  -0xc(%ebp),%eax` What is -0xc(%ebp) referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The arguments to the function are based in (`%ebp) + (positive value)` in your case you have 1 arguments.

and `(%ebp) - (positive value)` are local variables and you have 2 in your case.

[see the following image](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html):

[image]

You may read about [calling convention](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html) as well.

Comment: So you're saying `-0xc(%ebp),%eax` is an argument to my function? I thought that the parentheses around %ebp meant that this will be `(address contained in %ebp) - 0xc`?